# New hard drive on Dell Precision 490 not being detected

Tags: hard-drive, bios, dell-precision

I have been given an old computer dell precision 490 to run some tests on it and a new hard drive to install. But after placing the new hard drive and turning on the computer I get" Drive 0 not found: Serial ATA, SATA-0".

I saw as one of the causes might be that one needs to update the BIOS data and time. Not quite sure if that is the cause and how.

F2 will take me to the menu and I get "Drive ID= unknown" inside the drivers option. I did put two new hard drives inside the machine's two slots for the hard drive just to make sure the problem is not mechanical or electrical.

Any guides or help would be most appreciated.

Comment: This question is more likely to be on topic on [su], which is our sister site for enthusiast computer users; Server Fault is about professional server and network administration, which I don't think this question quite fits within the scope of. You can "flag" your question for moderator attention and request for it to be migrated if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How do I flag this. I am new to all this.

Comment: You should see a "flag" link to the left, just below the question tags which are in turn just below the question text. Click on that link, select "flag for moderator attention", and type into the box that you want the question migrated to Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer, inside bios select "load defaults" and press ok. That did it.

Comment: Which probably means that you just hadn't the slot being "enabled". Loading defaults most likely set the slot to being enabled thus having it be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

enter in bios settings and reset it to defaults. in HDD section, check hdd mode: Legacy mode - native Mode. select Native mode, this must correct your hard disk problem, good luck

Comment: Did you realize the OP answered the question below with what resolved the issue?